# PHP - how to create this SOAP XML request?

Tags: php, soap, data-structures, soap-client

I'm trying to figure out how to structure data properly in PHP in order to make a SOAP XML request like this:

```
<typ:saveRequest locationName="example.com">
    <typ:datatype owner="ME" class="OPEN">
        <typ:order>1</typ:order>
        <typ:datavalue>random@example.com</typ:datavalue>
    </typ:datatype>
</typ:saveRequest>
```

The PHP function looks like this:

```
$this->soapclient->saveRecord($dataparams);
```

How do I structure $dataparams to fit the above saveRequest? ie, something like:

```
$dataparams= array(
    'locationName' => $domain,
    ...
);
```

Comment: Just wondering - shouldn't the method match the soap acion? i.e $this->soapclient->saveRequest( array( order=>1, dataValue=>"random@example.com" ) ); You've got $this->soapclient->saveRecord

Comment: Sorry - yes, they are identical. I edited it before posting. The sample data content has been simplified as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still need help with this:

```
$dataparams= array(
    'datatype' => array('order' => 1, 'datavalue' => 'random@example.com',
);
```

then run

```
$this->soapclient->saveRequest($dataparams);
```

This should do it, in case I understood correctly. I am not sure about the location / owner / class but at least this could give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Use NuSOAP library for this that I find good.

An introduction is here http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapintro.htm#hw

Comment: Hi pMan - thanks for responding, but I dont want to use another library just because I can't figure out how to access this one properly... Thanks anyway!